# Group by and Count to select repeated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote this query but it does not work as I expected.

1st Goal: select rows that have repeated in certain columns and return whole columns.

2nd Goal: Update a flag (a column) to identify which records have repeated.

Could you please help me?

```
SELECT
  *
FROM AvvalV2NS AS M
WHERE EXISTS 

(SELECT
  M.Astate,
  M.Acity,
  M.Azone,
  M.Abvillage,
  M.Avillage,
  COUNT(*)
FROM AvvalV2NS AS M
GROUP BY M.Astate,
         M.Acity,
         M.Azone,
         M.Abvillage,
         M.Avillage
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Your query is a `select`.  How do you expect anything to be updated?  Sample data and desired results would help convey what you want to do.

Comment: I know but I first want to select them, after that I will use update.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the rows that are duplicated, window functions are probably the easiest way:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             count(*) over (partition by M.Astate, M.Acity,  M.Azone, M.Abvillage, M.Avillage) as cnt
      from AvvalV2NS a
     ) a
where cnt > 1;
```

You can update a flag by doing something like this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select a.*
      from (select a.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by M.Astate, M.Acity,  M.Azone, M.Abvillage, M.Avillage) as cnt
            from AvvalV2NS a
           ) a
     )
update toupdate
    set isduplicate = (case when cnt > 1 then 1 else 0 end);
```

Comment: @yousefyegane . . . Oops, I left out the `partition by `.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your table have an id column:

```
SELECT * FROM THE_TABLE WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT ID FROM 
    (SELECT ID, REPEATING_COLUMNS, COUNT(*) FROM THE_TABLE GROUP BY REPEATING_COLUMNS HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
)

UPDATE THE_TABLE SET THE_FLAG = "HERE WE GO" WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT ID FROM 
    (SELECT ID, REPEATING_COLUMNS, COUNT(*) FROM THE_TABLE GROUP BY REPEATING_COLUMNS HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no ID, that's the problem, and I am using 5 columns to make an identity.